# Boolean operations on polygons using Python

Tags: python, software-recommendations

I have 2 polygons and I would like to subtract one from the other. Is there any Python library that can do this for me?

In the image below I'm trying to subtract the darker polygon from the lighter one.

[image: Overlapping polygons]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: the term you are looking for is `difference`

Comment: Shapely has a [`difference`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.difference) binary operation.

Answer (score 1):

As Mike T mentioned above in the comments, the solution is to use the [difference](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.difference) method from the Shapely library.